# Database documents are deleted over time

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, nosql

As part of the exercises, I write an application in which I store data on the mongodb database. After a few days of doing exercises, I see that today it is completely empty. The collections were completely removed.

Is it possible in mongodb to create a list of logs that the database has performed and why the data has been deleted?

And is there anything that can automatically delete database contents over time?

I read about TTL but after turning it off, the situation repeated. I will be very grateful for all suggestions.

`server.js` file below:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const dbConfig = require('./config/database.config.js');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var fs = require('fs')
var https = require('https')
const path = require('path');
const port = 8080;


mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const app = express();
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.use('/views', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
require('./routes/orderRoutes')(app);


https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cert', 'key.pem')),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'cert','cert.pem'))
  }, app)
  .listen(3443, function () {
    console.log('app listening on port 3443!')
  })


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})

mongoose.connect(dbConfig.url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully connected to the database");    
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Could not connect to the database. Exiting now...', err);
    process.exit();
});
```

`database.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    url:'....' }
```

`cat /etc/mongod.conf`

```
# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo
```

Comment: This is not a normal behavior for any DB, can you please share the code of connecting with the db, also where is your db located on the server? It should primarily be in /var/data/mongo or something. This path can be set manually to a specific location as well.

Comment: I added the source code of the server file that connects to the database. 
I use a VPS on which I run a node with a database

Comment: Ok, so the code is not an issue, Its the location where the mongo db is getting stored. It may be getting stored on temporary locations like /var/log/* which is cleaned by the server at regular intervals. We can see the location in following file: /etc/mongod.conf

Just ssh login the server and run

``` cat /etc/mongod.conf ```

Comment: So you are right, the location of the data is where it is periodically deleted. Thank you very much for pointing to the error. Above I pasted the ssh query result

Comment: You resolved the issue by changing the location for db right?

Comment: So far, I have changed the location and I will observe the situation whether there are still deletions

Comment: Ok, thanks for the response.